# Could not find a valid parent module to add to the server when running Project on Websphere

Tags: java, eclipse, websphere

I am getting an error stating that "Could not find a valid parent module to add to the server" when I try to run an application on Websphere using Eclipse.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to run a web application on the server or an enterprise application? Traditional WebSphere does not support standalone web applications. Try including the web app in an enterprise app and deploy the enterprise app on the server.

Comment: I tried creating a new Enterprise Application from Java EE and pasted the code their but still receiving the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve this by adding `<project>PROJECT_NAME</project>` inside .project of the EAR Folder

[image]